# How to replace value of a column with condition in sql

Tags: sql

For example if I have 2 tables

| id | name | email |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Zack | zack@email.com |
| 2 | Adam | adam@email.com |
| 3 | Billy | billy@email.com |

| id | custId | email |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 0 | zack@email.com |
| 2 | 0 | adam@email.com |
| 3 | 0 | billy@email.com |

If I add a new column in the second table (`custId`) and by default the value is 0, if I want to change the value of it to id in the first table how should I  do it?

I tried to use

```
REPLACE INTO table2(custId)
    SELECT table2.id 
    FROM table1, table2 
    WHERE table1.email = table2.email
```

Result:

| id | custId | email |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 0 | zack@email.com |
| 2 | 0 | adam@email.com |
| 3 | 0 | billy@email.com |
| 4 | 1 | NULL |
| 5 | 2 | NULL |
| 6 | 3 | NULL |

What I'm trying to achieve:

| id | custId | email |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | zack@email.com |
| 2 | 2 | adam@email.com |
| 3 | 3 | billy@email.com |

Comment: What version of MySQL are you using?

Comment: Why are you using `REPLACE INTO` instead of `UPDATE`?

Comment: `update table2 set email = (select custId from table1 t1 where t1.email = table2.email)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To retrieve the custId from *table1* we can use `inner join` by the column email, and to update we use the `update` clause

```
update table2 t2
inner join table1 t1 on t1.email = t2.email
set custId = t1.id
```

[Demo here](https://dbfiddle.uk/8uiAZ5SU)